# Drag and Drop UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I have some pics on my `View` its `UserControl` that `Binding` from `ObservableCollection` from `ViewModel`. I made `allowDrop` `true` and wrote `DragOver` method, but how I can receive pic/pics and add them to my collection?

Here some code:

```
<Grid    
    Margin="0,0,0,0" 
    AllowDrop="True"
    Drop="<!--Dont know what to do-->">

 <Image
Source="{x:Bind Image}"
```

`Image` uses in `DataTemplate` and `Binding` to `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Did you start at [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/drag-and-drop?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#process-the-drop-event)?

Comment: Yes i read `Process the Drop event` but I can use it only in codebehind

Comment: Dragging/dropping is under the purview of the view, so it should be handled in the codebehind.

Comment: @Will do mean make it in codebehind than add this collection to my(on VM)?

Comment: Yep.  There are frameworks out there that propose to make the process easier, and more MVVM, but unless you want to do a lot of work for it, just add it in your codebehind.  The frameworks take a lot of effort to get everything set up, but are better in the long run if you've got lots of drag/drop orperations of different types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote behavior for this on `XAML` control

```
 <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:ItemDropBihevior ItemDropCommand="{Binding ImageManipulatorViewModel.DropImageCommand, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"/>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Drop">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction  CommandParameter="{Binding}">
            </core:InvokeCommandAction>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

And then catch at `ViewModel` and put to my colection